# Canonical partition function, simple model of 2D polymer

Tags: statistical-mechanics, simulations, polymers

I am trying to simulate using monte-carlo method the behavior of a simple of polymer.

The model -
The polymer is made of N bars with length a , each bar can be placed in +a or -a relative to
the end of the last bar.
An external force f in the positive x direction is acting on the polymer so that the Hamiltonian is

$H = -fa\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_x,_i $

where $\sigma_x$ is the x direction of the bar.
according to this I got the partition function -

$Z = \sum_{{\sigma_y}_{1,2,..n} {= 0 , \pm 1} , {\sigma_x}_{1,2,..n} {= 0 , \pm 1}}\exp(-\beta H) = (2+\exp(\beta fa)+\exp(-\beta fa))^{N}    $

when I assumed that the position of each bar is independent of the previous one

To test this model I tried to simulate the Polymer in matlab for diffrent forces and calculate the mean and variance of the total length in the x axis.
From the partition function I derived the mean to be - $<\Delta x >_{c} = \frac{1}{f} \frac{\partial ln(Z)}{\partial \beta} = aN\tanh(\frac{\beta fa}{2}) $
and variance to be $<\Delta x>^{2}_c =\frac{1}{f^{2}} \frac{\partial ^{2} ln(Z)}{\partial ^{2} \beta}  = \frac{a^{2}N}{2\cosh (\frac {\beta fa}{2})^{2}}  $

using this model and a = 1 I ran a matlab simulation and got the following results -
[image][image]

As you can see the mean values I got behave in a similar manner to those derived from the partition function although there seems that some factor is missing , but the variance seems to be completely off.
I tried to fix my calculation but couldn't find what causes this error , is there something I am missing in the partition function?
any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What value of the various parameters (most importantly what value of $N$) are you using for these plots? This is important if we are to know which value for the variance (if either) looks reasonable

Comment: I am using N = $ 10^{3} $  , the simulation runs for bfa from 0 to 4 in steps of 0.2 and in each run I am doing $ 10^{6} $ steps. I apply  the force by calculating the factor $ \exp (-  \beta (\sigma _{xNEW} - \sigma _{xOLD})) $ , if this factor is less then a rand number between 0 and 1 I swap the direction of the current bar with new random direction.